# How to wait for a duration before a sequence is run?

Tags: swift, wait, skaction

I'm making a game with SpriteKit, and when it starts, I have nodes that spawn and fall from the top of the screen:

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2, withRange: 0.19)
let spawn = SKAction.runBlock {
    self.addTears()
}
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
```

Before these nodes spawn, I want to wait for a duration of 1 second, but only when the game starts. I tried to add a waitForDuration before I run the sequence but it didn't work.

Comment: What about it didn't work?

Comment: I ran the program and it didn't wait for a duration of 1 second. I didn't have any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
let otherWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
let otherSequence = SKAction.sequence([otherWait, SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)])
runAction(otherSequence)
```